# HTML/CSS How to have to tags on same line?

Tags: html, css

I don't know if that's exactly the right title for this question and I'm sorry, anyway... So I've been learning HTML and CSS for the past couple of days. I would like to say I've been progressing quite a bit and I came across an issue. I made a ul list with a couple li's in there and I wanted to make them both on the same line (The top of the screen, a bit how stack overflow looks with the drop down being the heading and the news feed and questions being the ul list). However in the video I watched it told me to do this:

```
h1 {
    margin 0;
    display: inline;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

And in the video the ul was now horizontal instead of being vertical. I've been searching online for a while and couldn't find anything so I had to come here. Now I'm wondering if someone could give me the correct code to solve the issue and have the heading and the ul on the same row at the top of the screen and in fact if I could gain a link of some kind to finding a better way of learning HTML and CSS? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example would put two `ul`s side-by-side, but would do nothing for `li`s inside the `ul`s.

Instead, you want:

```
li {
  display: inline;   // or inline-block
}
```

Example:

```css
h1 {
    margin 0;
    display: inline;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}

li {
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin: 0;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>

<ul>
  <li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood him. he wants the li elements next to each other.

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped somewhat? It did make the text horizontal however it is not on the same line as the h1? Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Just added that to the example.

Comment: Correction. This did in fact work and I am sorry for my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `display: inline` to the `li` instead of the `ul`. See http://jsfiddle.net/Lcwc1z95/:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the li elements also inline, such as:

```
h1 {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  display:  inline;
}

ul li {
  display:  inline;
}
```

An example with the h1 title on http://jsfiddle.net/osw872hb/